# How to create a account record using apex and lwc which is used in Salesforce one app

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, barcode

I have a lwc component which does some qrcode scanning and displays the result in the .then block and this scanner only works in salesforce one app. I want to create a new account with the scanned value in description field. I am using the below code to do so in my LWC Component;

```
handleBeginScanClick(event) {
        this.scannedBarcode = '';
        if (this.myScanner != null && this.myScanner.isAvailable()) {
            //Formats that can be scanned
            const scanningOptions = {
                barcodeTypes: [this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.QR, 
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.UPC_E,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.CODE_128,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.CODE_39,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.CODE_93,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.EAN_13,
                    this.myScanner.barcodeTypes.EAN_8]
            };
            this.myScanner
                .beginCapture(scanningOptions)
                .then((result) => {
                    this.scannedBarcode = decodeURIComponent(result.value);
                    const accRecord = {Name:"Testing"};
                    saveAccount({objAcc:accRecord})   //My apex method is here
                    .then(result => {
                        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success!!',
                            message: 'Account Created Successfully!!',
                            variant: 'success'
                        })
                        );
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        alert("Reached into error block");
                        this.error = error.message;
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Barcode Scanner Error',
                            message:
                                'There was a problem scanning the barcode: ' +
                                JSON.stringify(error) +
                                ' Please try again.',
                            variant: 'error',
                            mode: 'sticky'
                        })
                    );
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.myScanner.endCapture();
                });
        } else {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Barcode Scanner Is Not Available',
                    message:
                        'Try again from the Salesforce app on a compatible device.',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }
    }
```

Below is my apex code to create account;

```
public with sharing class BarcodeController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Account saveAccountRecord(Account objAcc){
        try{
            insert objAcc;
            return objAcc;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But i am not able to create account

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your code looks fine except the apex code. You can't do DML from a cached method. Whenever you run into any error the first step you need to follow is to put the debug logs. If you check the apex debug logs, you must be getting some error like below

> Too many DML statements: 1

Just remove the `(cacheable=true)` from the apex class and you should be able to create the record.

> The reason Salesforce does not allow DML in the cached method is that
> these methods don't get executed when there is a cache hit.

Try the below code.

```
public with sharing class BarcodeController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account saveAccountRecord(Account objAcc){
        try{
            insert objAcc;
            return objAcc;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, Yes this got fixed as you said. Thanks for your reply